# Drop duplicate / Get the unique value

Tags: visualization, tableau

Any idea how to drop duplicate values by 2 columns?

Here is the example. I want to get the first row if there's a duplicate value by 2 columns (customer_id , orderid)

[image: Example]

I've done with making a count distinct by new variable (concat customer id and order id ), but the value isn't correct yet.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this inside Tableau worksheet: use Index() calculation **by** *cust_key* and filter out anything not equal to 1.
[image]

But usually this type of things are handled in the initial SQL.